# SSIS Skip a container if table is empty

Tags: ssis

I have a package in SSIS with two sequence containers.
I want to create a logic that if one table on SQL is empty the SSIS should not run the first container and skip to second container._

How is the best approach to do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could begin with an execute SQL task to count the rows in the table. Then direct the flow based on the result.

Start by creating a variable to save the results to.

[image: Variable]

Use Execute SQL Task to get count of records in the table. Set ResultSet to Single Row and create your query to count rows in the table. Save the Result Set to the variable you created.

`Select count (*) FROM [YourTable]`

[image: Execute SQL Task]

[image: Result Set]

Use the Precedence Constraint to direct the flow to Task One or Task Two depending on the results of the TableCount.

[image: Control Flow]

[image: TableCount = 0]

[image: TableCount > 0]

Comment: Thanks but the flow if different. I have a container A that is connect to container B. If the tables is empty the SSIS should do A - B. but if table is not null they obly should do B. You suggestion does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Put B in it's own package.

In new package add Exec SQL Task like Don suggests and lead it to:

1. Container A connected to exec package (program to run B's package). And connect Exec SQL to Container A with precedence like Don did.
2. Also connect to exec package (that runs B) and connect like Don did with precedence constraint.

You package will flow down one side. A-B if empty. Or straight to B if not empty.

This is treating Container B as a method with this logic.

```
if(sqlCount==0)
{
   RunA();
   RunB();
}
else
{
   RunB();
}
```